# ERROR: si-contact-form.php plugin says imagepng function

Tags: php

In my website im using fast secure contact form, i have enabled captcha in it, after that it is throwing the following error

> ERROR: si-contact-form.php plugin says imagepng function not detected in PHP! 
>   Contact your web host and ask them why imagepng function is not enabled for PHP.

I think that the error is due to captcha can anyone help me to resolve it ?

Comment: No, the error is to do with the fact that `imagepng()` is undefined, which means you need to install the `php5-gd` package from your distro's package manager (assuming you're using Linux). If you're on shared hosting and they won't do this for you, you're out of luck. Have you tried solving this _yourself_?

Comment: ok, i will define the function in the server

Answer (score 1):

Install php-gd package

```
sudo apt-get install php-gd
```

and restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

if you are using php5 this may be the correct package

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

---

this may help to find the relevant package

```
sudo apt-cache search php | grep gd
```